# Jquery not sending data to WCF in a post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, json

Hi guys running into a bit of an issue with WCF.  For some reason I'm not sending any data at all or I get 500 internal server error... which means WCF has no idea what I'm sending. If I change to WrappedRequest I can hit the service, just nothing is sent. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Here is the javascript

```
var data = { UserId: 2, Name: "test" };
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:54900/MyService.svc/SaveName',
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: $.toJSON(data),
                    error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert('success');
                    }
                });

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle
= WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

found the problem.  Had to remove enablewebscript and leave it at webHttp. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your data to your WCF service from different way when you use the "WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare" option.

you need to add the value of your parameters at the end of your url instead of the date of your ajax call, something like this:
url: 'http://localhost:54900/MyService.svc/SaveName/parameters'.

FYI- just need to add the value not the name of your parameters.

also you need to add another property to your method on the WCF service, this is the UriTemplate, this must be formated like this:

UriTemplate = "/theNameOfYourMethod/{firstNameOfYourParameter}/{second...}"

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Chris
Done by mistake. It was not intentional